Azure Devops: Stage Output is not resolved correctly
I have this weird issue with a pipeline template that I am currently trying to make work for different Angular/.NET builds:
The Pipeline references 3 stages: Prework, Angular and Backend.
In the Prework stage the GitVersion is fetched:
          - task: gitversion/setup@0
            displayName: "Install GitVersion v${{parameters.gitVersion}}"
            inputs:
              versionSpec: "${{parameters.gitVersion}}"

          - task: gitversion/execute@0
            displayName: Determine Version
            name: CreateVersions
            inputs:
              targetPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
              useConfigFile: true
              configFilePath: ${{parameters.gitVersionFilePath}}
            
          - powershell: |
              Write-host "Version to build: $(GitVersion.SemVer)"
              Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=version;isOutput=true]$(GitVersion.SemVer)"
            displayName: "Setup version"
            name: Versions

That works on every repository.
However the next stage the gitVersion is resolved correctly to a version number in all repositories but one.
In the one case where it doesn't work I get this during ng build in the angular stage:
npm ERR! Invalid version: "$[stageDependencies.Prework.General.outputs[CreateVersions.GitVersion.SemVer]]" 
Every occurence of the version number looks like above and it is generally not resolved in the next stage.
I use exactly the same pipeline template and main template and really don't know where to start looking.
I checked for shallow fetch to be disabled, played around with with the Syntax, checked for Pipeline Settings being different.
Disclaimer: I am a student and new to Azure DevOps and therefore lack experience.

SO is for programming questions

Try to use $[stageDependencies.Prework.General.outputs['Versions.version']] in your angular stage.
- stage: Angular 
  dependsOn: Prework
  jobs: 
  - job: Test
    variables:
      myStageAVar: $[stageDependencies.Prework.General.outputs['Versions.version']]
    steps:
      - bash: echo $(myStageAVar)

In the example above,

Prework is the name of the stage "Angular" depend on.
General is the job in which you set variable version.
Versions is the name of the PowerShell task in which you creat variable version.

